# Can I delete node_modules folder after compiling all required dependencies?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I have a project on Laravel 5.4; I'm absolutely new to front-end package managers. 
I used npm to install 4 packages in my project, so my `node_modules` folder has about 210 MB. 
I used Laravel Mix to combine in groups required dependencies and files, then I run `npm run dev`. 
My `webpack.mix.js` looks like :

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
   .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'public/js')

   .combine([
    'node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css',
    'node_modules/videojs-record/dist/css/videojs.record.css'],'public/css/recordDependencies.css')

   .combine([
    'node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js',
    'node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js',
    'node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js',
    'node_modules/videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.js',
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js',
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js',
    'node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js'
    ], 'public/js/recordDependencies.js');
```

So, it generates me this files. Making a small test, I replaced the node_js directory out of the project, and everything still works. 
So, the question is :

> Can I delete this huge folder - `node_modules`, or it must live in
>   kernel of my project, at the deploying as well ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In frontend applications node_modules are only required for compiling resources. You would not want to deploy node_modules because they contain unobfuscated code. Only deploy compiled files.